# In the oncreate() of my activity can I tell what intent launches my activity?

Tags: android

Android will call `onCreate()` of my activity whenever it is launched.

In the `onCreate()` of my activity can I tell what intent launches my activity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple - use `getIntent()`. You'll also want to override `onNewIntent(Intent intent)`. I usually write a method called `HandleIntent(Intent intent)` and call it from both `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`.